# Setup consul https with a previous certificate from tomcat

Tags: https, consul

How can we do to set up the consul use a previous certificate created for the tomcat?

We only have *server.jks* file used in tomcat, and we need to use the same tomcat certification.

How can we do to extract this information below?

```
"ca_file": "cert/ca.pem",
"cert_file": "cert/server.pem",
"key_file": /cert/serverkey.pem",
```

The server.conf

```
{
    "bootstrap": true,
    "server": true,
    "datacenter": "dc1",
    "data_dir": "data",
    "verify_incoming": true,
    "verify_outgoing": true,
    "verify_server_hostname": true,    
    "auto_encrypt": {
       "allow_tls": true
    },
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "enable_agent_tls_for_checks": true,
    "enable_syslog": false,
    "ui_config": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "ports": {
       "http": -1,
       "https": 8500
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail on what you are trying to achieve? Consul requires a specific common name (CN) to be present in the certificate for both clients and servers. You can find details about that in the following tutorial https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/tls-encryption-openssl-secure. You won't be able to use a certificate which was previously created for Tomcat, at least not for securing Consul's RPC communication.

Comment: Thanks for your time. HTTP is blocked to us. Basically, we need to expose consul UI in HTTPS, and the certificate generated by "consul tls ca create " doesn't work. 
This is the message from the browser:
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: You would need to import the public CA cert generated by `consul tls ca create` into your browser so that you can avoid the certificate warning. If you would just prefer to use your internal CA, you can follow the tutorial I linked, but sign the certificates using your internal CA. The CA's public cert should be provided to Consul using the `ca_file` option, with the public and private certs being configured via the `cert_file` and `key_file` options.